# Does naming function in MSSQL like fn_myFuction take additional performace

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, naming-conventions

Someone here mentioned that We should avoid naming stored procedures in MS SQL server like sp_XXX
Because that taking addition time to SQL server while check does exist system sotred procedure named like that. Because all system stored procs are starting with sp_.

Now I wondering is that a case with Functions in MSSQL, Does naming functions like fn_ take additional time to SQL while looking for system functions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think so.

Found the following thread:

http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/78872-udf-starting-fn_

> No. To call a system-supplied [User Defined Function], you
>   need to use ::, so that is what SQL
>   Server looks for. All system-supplied
>   UDFs are table functions, as scalar
>   system functions are not UDFs at all.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

For functions it does not matter, however it is recommended to **NOT** use a prefix of **sp_** for stored procedures as it defines a system stored procedure and may cause an extra lookup in the MASTER database.

> As sp_ prefix is reserved for system
>   stored procedure and any stored
>   procedure which has sp_ prefix will
>   cause an extra lookup in MASTER
>   database. There is another point to
>   note that if a stored procedure uses
>   same name, in user database as system
>   stored procedure in master database,
>   the stored procedure in user database
>   will never get executed as SQL Server
>   will always look first in master
>   database and will execute that one
>   rather one in user database.

http://furrukhbaig.wordpress.com/2007/08/22/stored-procedures-factssheet/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115.aspx